# Codewars/Direction Reduction algoritm too slow in C++

Tags: c++

I'm having hard time with the Direction Reduction task from Code Wars. While my solution passes the initial tests, it appears it's far too slow for the final submition.

The task:

"Once upon a time, on a way through the old wild mountainous west,…
… a man was given directions to go from one point to another. The directions were "NORTH", "SOUTH", "WEST", "EAST". Clearly "NORTH" and "SOUTH" are opposite, "WEST" and "EAST" too.
Going to one direction and coming back the opposite direction right away is a needless effort. Since this is the wild west, with dreadfull weather and not much water, it's important to save yourself some energy, otherwise you might die of thirst!
How I crossed a mountainous desert the smart way.
The directions given to the man are, for example, the following (depending on the language):

["NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST"].
or
{ "NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST" };
or
[North, South, South, East, West, North, West]

You can immediatly see that going "NORTH" and immediately "SOUTH" is not reasonable, better stay to the same place! So the task is to give to the man a simplified version of the plan. A better plan in this case is simply:

["WEST"]
or
{ "WEST" }
or
[West]

Other examples:

In ["NORTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST"], the direction "NORTH" + "SOUTH" is going north and coming back right away.

The path becomes ["EAST", "WEST"], now "EAST" and "WEST" annihilate each other, therefore, the final result is [] (nil in Clojure).

In ["NORTH", "EAST", "WEST", "SOUTH", "WEST", "WEST"], "NORTH" and "SOUTH" are not directly opposite but they become directly opposite after the reduction of "EAST" and "WEST" so the whole path is reducible to ["WEST", "WEST"].
Task

Write a function dirReduc which will take an array of strings and returns an array of strings with the needless directions removed (W<->E or S<->N side by side).

My solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>



class DirReduction
{
public:
    static std::vector<std::string> dirReduc(std::vector<std::string> &arr);
    static bool areOpposite(const std::string& x, const std::string& y);
    static std::vector<std::string> input;
    static bool firstRun;
};

std::vector<std::string> DirReduction::input;
bool DirReduction::firstRun = true;

std::vector<std::string> DirReduction::dirReduc(std::vector<std::string> &arr)
{
    if(firstRun)//on first run copy the input data in a new vector
    {
        input = {arr.begin(), arr.end()};
        firstRun = false; //set this to 'false' so it doesn't copy in subsequent calls
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < input.size()-1;)// go trough length-1
    {
        while(input.size() > 1 && areOpposite(input[i], input[i+1]))//check if neighboring entries are opposite
        {
            auto it = input.begin() + i;

            it = input.erase(it, it+2); //erase the two neighboring entries
            if(input.size() == 0)//if the vec is empty after removal just return it
            {
                firstRun = true;
                return input;
            }

            dirReduc(input);//Go again at the reduced vector
        }

             ++i;
    }

    firstRun = true;
    return input;
}

bool DirReduction::areOpposite(const std::string& x, const std::string& y)
{
    //this checks for either of the conditions
    if((x == "NORTH" && y == "SOUTH") || (x == "SOUTH" && y == "NORTH"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if((x == "EAST" && y == "WEST") || (x == "WEST" && y == "EAST"))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> d1 = {"NORTH", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST", "WEST", "WEST", "WEST" };
    std::vector<std::string> d2 = {"NORTH", "WEST", "SOUTH", "EAST"};
    std::vector<std::string> d3 = {"NORTH", "SOUTH"};
    std::vector<std::string> d4 = {"NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST"};
    std::vector<std::string> d5 = {"NORTH", "EAST", "WEST", "SOUTH", "WEST", "WEST"};

    std::vector<std::string> res = DirReduction::dirReduc(d1);

    if(res.size() == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Empty";
        }
    else
    {
            for(auto& it : res)
        {

            std::cout << it << " ";
        }
    }


}
```

Is there a way to make this run faster?

Comment: Please format your code consistently if you want people to read it. Also, you are asking two questions, which is bad. Further, questions about "optimize" and "wrong" are prone to opinionated answers, so please make sure to write what exactly you mean with those. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you can do to speed this up, but by far the most important is to **stop using recursion.**

Recursion has its uses, but it can be hideously inefficient, and in this case it is entirely unnecessary. If you look carefully at your `dirReduc`, you'll see that most of its activity does nothing, since each invocation of the function removes *one* opposing pair, at most. And yet each invocation churns through the entire vector, usually starting with a long stretch that has already been cleared, and ending with another long stretch that has already been cleared. (I know that sounds strange, but I invite you to have the function print out the vector it starts with, and each pair that it compares, perhaps with a 1-second delay in each iteration of the loop; you'll see what I mean.)

Rule out recursion, and you'll soon see a simpler, faster way.

Comment: Thank you! Solved it by removing the recursive part and just reset the i index at 0 after a matching pair. Test completed!